# Android Volley RequestQueue and ApplicationContext

Tags: android, android-volley

Going through android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html) noticed this paragraph:

> The recommended approach is to implement a singleton class that encapsulates RequestQueue and other Volley functionality. Another approach is to subclass Application and set up the RequestQueue in Application.onCreate(). But this approach is discouraged; a static singleton can provide the same functionality in a more modular way.

But there is no elaboration on why the second approach is discouraged. Any one has any insights?

Comment: Because its easier to mock out for unit testing than an Application constant.  But either way will work.

Comment: I have heard that argument about singletons in general. But I was looking at this googleblog that says the opposite: https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/05/tott-using-dependancy-injection-to.html

Comment: they're talking about something else entirely. Dependency injection vs singletons, not application hosted global vs singletons